# Checking for the reducibility of a polynomial using rational root theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

When checking for the reducibility of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$. I can either use the eisenstein criteria or contradiction. However, I am wondering if it is possible to use rational root theorem. If after testing for all the possible roots of a polynomial using rational root theorem, I can't find a root. Does it mean that the polynomial is not reducible? If not, why?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: Consider the polynomial $x^4+4$. It has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ however $x^4+4=(x^2+2)-(2x)^2=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$, hence reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$..

Comment: Look at the degrees of possible factors. cubics $\ 3 = 1+2, 2+1\,$ but quartics $\, 4 = 1+3,3+1,\color{#c00}{2+2}\ \ $ RRT only excludes *linear* factors, not $\rm\color{#c00}{quadratic}\,$ or higher degree factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducible polynomials are guaranteed to have roots in your base field **if** they are degree $3$ or less, since any reduction forces a term to be linear.   Higher-degree polynomials do not have this property.  An example would be $x^4 + 3x^2 + 2 = (x^2+1)(x^2+2)$, which is reducible but has no roots over $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

This only works for polynomials of degree $3$ or $2$. For example $(x^2-2)^2$ has no roots in $\mathbb Z$ but is definitely not irreducible.